# Select last N unique records mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "sessions" table that among other field has the following fields:

```
int int(11),
user_id int(11),
login_date timestamp,
ip varchar(15)
```

I want to select for each user the last login_date and the last three unique ips. How can I do this in an elegant way?

I found a solution but it's very very very ugly, ineffective, time consuming and involves a mix o mysql and bash scripting. How can I do this only in MySQL?

P.S. The table has cca 4.3 million rows.

Some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9ddd

Comment: can you show your `very very very ugly, ineffective, time consuming` way ?

Comment: I saved to a file unique user ids from this table. Then, for each uid, I get all the sessions, sort them by login date DESC and insert into a temp table. The first row will contain the last session and I select group_concat(ip) from (select distinct ip from temp_table limit 3)

Comment: Here's a solution slightly better than yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d65d/3. It still requires your client code to iterate over all user_ids though. I'm sure there's a way to achieve what you're looking for in a single query. I just don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a lot of time to convert in `MYSQL` from `SQL SERVER`

I have work on my Query for **better Performance**.

```
select 
user_id,
max(cast(login_date as datetime)),
group_concat(distinct ip order by login_date desc SEPARATOR  ' , ')
from 
(
SELECT 
  user_id,
  login_date,
  ip,
  CASE user_id 
   WHEN @curType 
    THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := user_id 
  END as sequence
FROM sessions, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY user_id asc,login_date desc
)t
where sequence<4
group by user_id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9ddd/91)**

Comment: +1 though one can not be sure, that the ip's belong to the latest entries. But since the OP didn't specify it exactly, this solution might as well be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This would get you the last date for each user_id

```
SELECT s1.* FROM sessions s1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sessions s2
ON s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.login_date < s2.login_date
WHERE s2.user_id IS NULL
```

and this will get you the unique IPs used for each user_id

`SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ip)) FROM sessions GROUP BY user_id`

then you can mix them,
getting it all together would be a bit more heavy on resources but I think it's doable.

good luck!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb209/71

Comment: Last login date can be selected much simpler - without joins. 
And selecting only 3 ip for each user is much harder than concatenating them all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id
    ,ip, 
    ,login_date
    ,IF(@user_id = SESSION_GRUOPED.user_id, @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=1 ) as row_id
    ,(@user_id:= SESSION_GRUOPED.user_id) as group_id
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, ip, max(login_date) login_date FROM SESSION group by user_id, ip order by user_id, login_date desc
  ) SESSION_GRUOPED 
    JOIN  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    JOIN  (select @user_id := 0) u
) RESULT
WHERE row_id < 4;
```

The key of the query is this part

`SELECT user_id, ip, max(login_date) login_date FROM SESSION group by user_id, ip order by user_id, login_date desc`

Thanks to it you get information about last login on given ip by each user.

Then you wrap this to set the result number in group, then you just limit the result to those are less then 4 as you want only three results for single user.

Note: If you change row_id < 4 into row_id = 1, the you will have the latest login of user.

Comment: @Luv, Thank you very much. I did not had chance to run it. So a little bug has found thanks to you link. The order was invalid for dates. Now is fine ;-).